# Too long execution of comparing operation of two mysql tables

Tags: mysql

I have vps Mem:524 (215used) Swap:524(75used) , mysql 5.1.61  with three tables.

Table 'new' with one column 'data' contains 100 000 records.

> record1
>
> record2
>
> record3

Table 'old' with one column 'data' contains 1 000 000 records.

> record1
>
> record4
>
> record5

Table 'result' with one column 'data' too.

I compare table 'new' with table 'old' and insert into table 'result' records which are not in table 'old'.  In this example it will be

> record2
>
> record3

I use the query

```
INSERT INTO result 

SELECT data FROM new 

LEFT JOIN old USING (data) 

WHERE old.data IS NULL
```

My problem - this query executes more than hour or maybe more (I can't wait more).

I would like to know more quick method of such mysql operation. Ideal - 10-20min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query will be faster :

```
insert into result
select data 
from new n
where not exists 
(select 1 from old where data = n.data)
```

And index on `data` filed in `new` and `old` tables (but not in `result` table) 
will improve the performance significantly.

You can add index by :

```
create index ind1 on old(data)
```

Comment: the same. More than hour execution and not finished yet

Comment: What is the type of `data` field ? What kind of values it contains?

Comment: data type: varchar(100) , value: ethomason
ethomas
ethstud
etico ,   index is not defined - may be this?

Comment: create index in `new` and `old` tables, it will run much faster.